# char[] messy output

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, maps, char

I have created a map that maps an int to a char. 0-25 to letters a-z and 26-35 0-9.

```
for(int i = 0; i<26; i++)
{
    letters.insert(Match::value_type(i,static_cast<char>(letter + x)));

    x++;
}

for(int i = 26; i<36; i++)
{

    letter = '0' + a;
    letters.insert(Match::value_type(i,letter));
    a++;
}
```

Here `i` input the `pin[]` which contains a number and look for the value.

```
std::map<int, char >::const_iterator it1 = letters.find(pin[0]);
std::map<int, char >::const_iterator it2 = letters.find(pin[1]);
std::map<int, char >::const_iterator it3 = letters.find(pin[2]);
std::map<int, char >::const_iterator it4 = letters.find(pin[3]);
char fourth  = it4->second;
char third   = it3->second;
char second  = it2->second;
char first   = it1->second;
char combo[] = { first, second, third, fourth};
cout << combo << endl;
```

Everything works fine but my `cout<< combo` gives me "abcd[[[[[a[[[[[b[[[[c[[[[[d]]]]]pPP."
I don't understand why... all I want in the output is just "abcd" How  can i clean it  up.

Comment: sorry. for some reason it got cut out, but here it is

Comment: i don't understand @JesseGood. my combo is null???

Comment: Take the effort to format your code. Code is complex enough without noise and distraction. You want to be able to see your code as intended, without 'accidentals'. ***Especially*** so if you expect others to read your code.

Comment: Btw, what is the reason to use `std::map` for letters? I'm suggesting to use `inline` function to convert via `static_cast`.

Comment: @user1665569: If you want to pretend that a character array is a string in order to print it, then it needs a zero valued character (aka "null terminator") to mark the end. That's how old-school C-style strings work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char combo[] = { first, second, third, fourth};
```

defines an array that contains sequence of 4 characters, but not a *null-terminated* string that could be printed. When `cout << combo` is being executed, the output stream treats this array as a common
C-style string, i.e. it tries to print all characters till it reaches `'\0'`. Try:

```
char combo[] = { first, second, third, fourth, '\0'};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to *null-terminate* your string to be able to use it in C-style mode. So this would change to:

```c
char combo[] = { first, second, third, fourth, '\0'};
```

Right now you're outputing the garbage you have in memory after `fourth` until a `null` character is found.